# How to show tooltip only when there is no activity?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a tooltip to show some information. It is displayed in 3 seconds.

The problem is that if I am scrolling the datagrid with the wheel of the mouse, to search a row, the tooltip is shown and it keeps shown although I am scrolling, so many of the rows are hidden by  the tooltip.

Is it some way to set the tooltip to be shown only when there is no activity but start to count the seconds if I use the keys or the wheel of the mouse to search a row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is generally possible. the easiest way would be to modify the tooltip placement or to adjust the show delay.

You can control the tooltip behavior using the [`ToolTipService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice?view=netframework-4.8) which exposes a set of attached properties:

```
<Ellipse Height="25" Width="50" 
      Fill="Gray" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="1000"
      ToolTipService.ShowDuration="7000"
      ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="2000"
      ToolTipService.Placement="Right" 
      ToolTipService.PlacementRectangle="50,0,0,0"
      ToolTipService.HorizontalOffset="10" 
      ToolTipService.VerticalOffset="20"
      ToolTipService.HasDropShadow="false"
      ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="true" 
      ToolTipService.IsEnabled="true"
      ToolTipOpening="whenToolTipOpens"
      ToolTipClosing="whenToolTipCloses"
      >
  <Ellipse.ToolTip>
    <BulletDecorator>
      <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
        <Ellipse Height="10" Width="20" Fill="Blue"/>
      </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
      <TextBlock>Uses the ToolTipService class</TextBlock>
    </BulletDecorator>
  </Ellipse.ToolTip>
</Ellipse>
```

---

If this doesn't satisfy your requirements, you can trigger the tooltip directly by setting the `ToolTiupService.IsEnabled` attached property. This requires the updating of the focus, because once the tooltip is disabled and has disappeared, the user has to trigger the tooltip again. For this reason I would rather toggle the `TooTip.Opacity` instead.

Another problem is that the actual column is not part of the data grid's visual tree.
To handle this somewhat problematic circumstances I introduced a static property for binding the template to it. Since the property is static and we need the `PropertyChanged` notification (`DependencyProperty` won't work as it is instance related), I also implemented a static `INotifyPropertyChanged` version.

The solution is based on an attached behavior, which listens to the routed `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` event to toggle the `ToolTip.Opacity` via data binding:

**DataGrid.cs**

```
class DataGrid : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  #region IsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabled attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabled", 
    typeof(bool), 
    typeof(DataGrid), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabledChanged));

  public static void SetIsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) 
    => attachingElement.SetValue(DataGrid.IsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabledProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement)
    => (bool) attachingElement.GetValue(DataGrid.IsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabledProperty);

  #endregion IsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabled attached property

  private static double opacityValue;   
  public static double OpacityValue
  {
    get => opacityValue;
    set 
    {
      opacityValue = value; 
      OnStaticPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private static DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; }

  static DataGrid()
  {
    DataGrid.Timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    // Set reset tooltip reappearance to 3 seconds 
    DataGrid.Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

    DataGrid.Timer.Tick += OnTimerElapsed;
    DataGrid.OpacityValue = 1.0;
  }

  private static void OnIsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabledChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid))
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("Attaching element must be of type DataGrid");
    }

    var behaviorIsEnabled = (bool) e.NewValue;
    if (behaviorIsEnabled)
    {
      EnableScrollHandling(dataGrid);
    }
    else
    {
      DisableScrollHandling(dataGrid);
    }
  }

  private static void EnableScrollHandling(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid)
  {
    if (dataGrid.IsLoaded)
    {
      dataGrid.AddHandler(ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnScrollChanged));
    }
    else
    {
      dataGrid.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
        dataGrid.AddHandler(ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnScrollChanged));
    }
  }

  private static void DisableScrollHandling(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid)
  {
    dataGrid.RemoveHandler(ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnScrollChanged));
  }

  private static void OnScrollChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    DataGrid.OpacityValue = 1.0;

    // Start or reset the timer on scroll
    DataGrid.Timer.Start();
  }

  private static void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var timer = sender as DispatcherTimer;
    timer.Stop();
    DataGrid.IsToolTipVisible = true;
    DataGrid.OpacityValue = 1.0;
  }

  public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
  private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    DataGrid.StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<!-- Enable the behavior by setting IsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabled to true -->
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" 
          DataGrid.IsDisableToolTipOnScrollEnabled="True">
  <DataGrid.Resources>

    <!-- Bind the ToolTip.Opacity to the static property of the attached behavior -->
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
      <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{Binding Path=(viewModels:DataGrid.OpacityValue)}" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>

  <!-- Setup the cell tooltips -->
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Value}" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```